# Exportable Zipkin/Brave/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth Span cannot be found in Zipkin

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I can't find a below **exportable** Span in Zipkin neither by it's traceId nor by spanId (some other spans appear, so Zipkin server seems to work)

```
{"timestamp":"2020-08-13 00:48:52.471","level":"INFO","thread":"xxx dispatcher: xxx","mdc":{"traceId":"481bef72295477ac","spanId":"509cdbbac8833590",
"spanExportable":"true","X-Span-Export":"true","X-B3-SpanId":"509cdbbac8833590","X-B3-ParentSpanId":"37eca1021fd5241c","X-B3-TraceId":"481bef72295477ac",
"parentId":"37eca1021fd5241c"},"logger":"xxxService","message":"Sending response xxxMsg to RabbitMQ channel","context":"default"}
```

I also can't find it's parent "parentId":"37eca1021fd5241c" in Zipkin.

Where can be a problem? How can I bite/debug it?

Possibly this span is in a flow, that was triggered by a rabbit message, not a rest request. Spans from a trace that were triggered by http rest request are correctly visible in Zipkin. But I can't find traces from flows triggered by rabbit message. What problem could be here?

Comment: You can go to zipkin, export the whole trace and search for those spans in the exported json

Comment: Problem is somewhere in Zipkin server itself. Maybe it's running out of memory and deletes old spans? Maybe it has some default number of detained traces in some circular buffer? How can it be checked and configured? It's openzipkin/zipkin:2.21.5 run on okd openshift in some basic default conf (possibly docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin). After about one minute I can't go into details of trace from search page to which I could go before moment.

Comment: You can ask about this in zipkin gitter chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using it with default storage which is discouraged in production use, it can handle only small amount of data and can be treated only as a demo version.

What helped a little was setting

`spring.sleuth.sampler.probability: 0.01`

-- by default it logs all spans.